# Deletion of records using in condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I need to delete records from legacy table using a reference table. Records to be deleted are around 300K and the performance is taking a hit as I'm using below query. Is there a better way to delete so that there wouldn't be any performance impact like using cursor ?

```
DELETE FROM LEG_EMP WHERE EMP_ID IN (SELECT ROW_ID FROM EMP_REF)
```

EMP_REF table ROW_ID equates with EMP_ID from LEG_EMP table.

I created indexes on columns EMP_ID and ROW_ID.

Created indexes and delete statements.

Comment: Is it a one-time operation?

Comment: Yes, it is just a one time execution to delete. However the window to delete is less as we are allowed to delete 300K records within the 10 min approved downtime.

Comment: And a 10 minute window is too short? Try smaller batches.

Comment: 300k records to delete out of how many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

Whenever I have to delete million rows, I always use an anonymous PL/SQL block with deleting chunks of rows (10,000 to 50,000 rows depending on the row size and commit them after each loop of 10,000 or 50,000 rows). This will ensure your rollback size is limited to that extent.
This has been the fastest way I used to delete millions of rows from a table.
It would be something like this given below:

```
DECLARE    
  v_row NUMBER;
  v_sqlStr VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  v_sqlStr := 'DELETE FROM tbl1 where <condition> AND ROWNUM < 10000';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_sqlStr: '|| v_sqlStr); 
  v_row := 1;
  WHILE v_row > 0 LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sqlStr;
   v_row := SQL%rowcount;
   commit;
END LOOP;   

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error in procedure deleteFromTable.'||      
SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000)); 
END ;
```

## Solution 2

1. Run an explain plan on your delete query
   DELETE FROM LEG_EMP WHERE EMP_ID IN (SELECT ROW_ID FROM EMP_REF)
   Where is the time being spent more on? Is it fetching data (or) waiting on
   data? Based on the wait event, you can determine appropriate course of
   action.
2. Verify you have an index on EMP_ID and see if the explain plan returns the query.
3. If you don't have an index on EMP_ID, add one and try it

## Solution 3

May be, see if you can partition the legacy table based on what you want to keep and what you want to delete and then drop the partition which you don't need. That may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exists` instead:

```
delete from leg_emp e
where exists (select null
              from emp_ref r
              where r.row_id = e.emp_id
             );
```